# Pandas DataFrame contains NaNs after write operation

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a minimum working example of my problem:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], range(2)])
a = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=range(3),columns=columns, dtype='float')
b = pd.Series([13.0, 15.0])

a.loc[1,'b'] = b  # this line results in NaNs
a.loc[1,'b'] = b.values  # this yields correct behavior
```

Why is the first assignment incorrect? Both Series seem to have the same index, so I assume it should produce the correct result.

I am using pandas 0.17.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
a.loc[1,'b'] = b
```

and `b` is a Series, the index of `b` has to exactly match the indexer generated by `a.loc[1,'b']` in order for the values in `b` to be copied into `a`. It turns out, however, that when `a.columns` is a `MultiIndex`, [the indexer for `a.loc[1,'b']`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L594) is:

```
(Pdb) p new_ix
Index([(u'b', 0), (u'b', 1)], dtype='object')
```

whereas the index for `b` is

```
(Pdb) p ser.index
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

They don't match, and therefore

```
(Pdb) p ser.index.equals(new_ix)
False
```

Since the values aren't aligned, [the code branch you fall into](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L602) assigns

```
(Pdb) p ser.reindex(new_ix).values
array([ nan,  nan])
```

I found this by adding `pdb.set_trace()` to your code:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], range(2)])
a = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=range(3),columns=columns, dtype='float')
b = pd.Series([13.0, 15.0])
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
a.loc[1,'b'] = b  # this line results in NaNs
a.loc[1,'b'] = b.values  # this yields correct behavior
```

and simply stepping through it at a "high level" and finding [the problem occurs in](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L350)

```
        if isinstance(value, ABCSeries):
            value = self._align_series(indexer, value)
```

and then stepping through it again (with a finer-toothed comb) with a break point starting at the line calling `self._align_series(indexer, value)`.

---

Notice that if you change the index of `b` to also be a MultiIndex:

```
b = pd.Series([13.0, 15.0], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['b'], [0,1]]))
```

then

```
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], range(2)])
a = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=range(3),columns=columns, dtype='float')
b = pd.Series([13.0, 15.0], index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['b'], [0,1]]))
a.loc[1,'b'] = b  
print(a)
```

yields

```
   a      b      c   
   0  1   0   1  0  1
0  0  0   0   0  0  0
1  0  0  13  15  0  0
2  0  0   0   0  0  0
```

Comment: In my case `b` is actually a temporary Series obtained from slicing another  DataFrame (with no MultiIndex). Is there a way to solve this without storing that temporary Series and reindexing it?

Comment: I think the easiest workaround is the one you showed -- assign a non-indexed object: `a.loc[1,'b'] = b.values`.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly assign `b` to a column in `a`, because `b` is not a multiindex Series. Changing `b` will make it work:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b', 'c'], range(2)])
a = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=range(3),columns=columns, dtype='float')
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['b'], range(2)])
b = pd.Series([13.0, 15.0], index=index)

a.loc[1,'b'] = b
print(a)
```

yields

```
   a      b      c
   0  1   0   1  0  1
0  0  0   0   0  0  0
1  0  0  13  15  0  0
2  0  0   0   0  0  0
```

---

The other case, where you use `b.values`, likely works because Pandas takes the values in `b` at face value, and tries to do the most logical assignment for the supplied values.